# What is the difference between data association and feature matching in SLAM/VO?

Tags: ros, slam

I have read a little bit about it and saw for Instance the terms used interchangably or that feature matching is part of data association. In "An Overview to Visual Odometry and Visual SLAM: Applications to Mobile Robotics" by Yousif et. al. it is said, that "…feature matching is the process of individually extracting features and matching them over multiple frames" but also that "DA is deﬁned as the process of associating a measurement (or feature) to its corresponding previously extracted feature.", but separetes them from each other. Other things i read about weren't that clear but mostly seem to indicate that feature matching is part of DA. Im a little bit confused.

Comment: You are right, feature matching is used for DA. The term "Feature matching" is used when the observations are images. To match the consecutive observations, image features are used. If the observations are 2D laser scans, terms like scan matching or map matching are used in case 2D SLAM.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Doyou know, if that means that sum of square diffrences and matching features via hamming distance of extractet bitstrings is both feature matching and therefore part of DA?

Comment: There are no hard definitions for these terms. In your case, you can say feature matching is part of DA.

Answer (score 0):

Data Association methods are the ones where we choose how do we find the transformations between two images. There are as follows:

1. Features points
2. Image patches around the features -semi dense methods/ semi direct
3. pixel to pixel - direct/optical flow based methods